# How do I show data based on the currently selected week in a WeekPicker and how to still be able to swipe through the data with a swipe animation?

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker, swipe, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I am currently developing an Xamarin Forms application for a customer. The app should show data, based on the current week selected in a `Picker`. The app needs a functionality to swipe between the data as well. So the week, of which the data should be shown, can be selected via the `Picker` or with a swipe gesture (with animation). Swiping should show the next/previous week.
But the problem is that I don't know how to implement this as efficient as possible. Is there any best practice to do this?
I have thought of a `CarouselView`, but as the Weeks are infinite, and swiping/loading should as well be possible with past weeks, I don't think that this is a good approach.

Comment: you could use any sort of UI element to display the week and add a swipe recognizer to allow the user to go forward/back

Comment: is there a way to implement a beautiful animation with a swipe recognizer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [CurrentItemChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction#respond-to-the-current-item-changing) Event.

You just have to create a Listener (via Event or CommandBinding) which searchs for the element in your pickerelement list and sets the currently selected index of the picker as the index of the searched element.

Comment: Otherwise you could use the [PositionChange](https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexander-zumpf-b7353920b/) Event on the carousel to change the index of the picker